# How do I use AND OR and NOT logic in searches?

Tags: support, tags, search

I'm following Atwood's post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1726/157337) and he gives an example on how to search questions with the tag [bug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), but not the wildcard tag [tag:status-*].

How would I use this to search for, as an example, all questions with "star" in the tag, but not questions with "wars" in a tag, so the end result would have all of [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), all of [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate), but no [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) questions?

Comment: [Wildcard tag searches are currently broken](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/add-ability-to-use-wildcarded-tags-in-search)

Comment: Wild card search is working for me. Nut I can't figure out how to search with NOT logic

Comment: You can search `[star-*]` or `[star-trek] [stargate] -[star-wars]`. Also, I'm dupe-closing this since I've now posted a definitive proposed-FAQ question about the search facility.